# Access an element by id inside Jupyter notebook _repr_javascript_ method

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I cannot retrieve a newly added html object using its id while inside the Jupyter output cell. How can I do it?

EDIT: I have been able to replicate the same behavior in a notebook hosted on Azure:

https://notebooks.azure.com/rickteachey/projects/sandbox/html/js_repr_id_access.ipynb

NOTE: to run this notebook, click `Clone` at the top right and run it in your own Azure project/notebook.

The javacript first adds a new html button using the Jupyter API (ie, `element.html()`; in context, `element` refers to the Jupyter output cell `<div>`).

Then the code attempts to access the button using `document.getElementById()`:

```
class C:
    def _repr_javascript_(self):
        return f'''
        element.html(`<button id="clearBtn">Clear</button>`)
        var x = document.getElementById("clearBtn")
        alert(x)
        '''

C()
```

EXPECTED BEHAVIOR: The alert should show a stringified version of the `clearBtn` html button object.

ACTUAL BEHAVIOR: The alert shows a null object, which means the script fails to grab the clearBtn - even though I can see it in the DOM when I look at the source.

It's possible I'm using the API incorrectly. If so, how am I supposed to do this?

Another weird issue: when I look at the same notebook on nbviewer, the alert pops up the clearBtn html object as expected. It does NOT behave this way on my local machine(s), or on Azure. Should I report this as a bug?

https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/dl.dropbox.com/s/dwfmnozfn42w0ck/access_by_id_SO_question.ipynb

Comment: Hi Rick, after running your Jupyter, nothing seems strange to me, if you are getting the alert saying "[object HTMLButtonElement]" it's ok, it just means that the JS interpreter tryed to stringify the object and ended up with this (not very useful) syntax.
If you want more infos on this object, i suggest you change the alert line by `console.log(x)` and open the [dev tool console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) to look at your object in more details

Comment: as i can see, the online version you shared is runned by [Online Jupyter engine](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org). I suggest you check the jupyter version you're localy running and compare it with the online engine's [version](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/releases)

Comment: Rick, debugging javascript code is not very difficult. The breakpoint method works fine you can also debug with the console's output but i'll let you make your choice from [this doc](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp)
For your code I suggest the console approach as it seems difficult to add breakpoint in your "stringy python inserted" javascript code

Comment: I see two possible answers.
 - Eather the button does not exist yet when you execute the javascript code (easy to check,try to find DOM elements while running the js code)
 - Eather the js code is run inside python only and does not have access to the DOM (maybe check how the nbviewer python is linked to the jupyter page and compare it with your setup)

Comment: I hope you good luck with this tricky one ... Another suggestion i might have is try to capture the return of your first line `element.html('<button id="clearBtn">Clear</button>')`, maybe you can have direct access to the button this way (if it's what you want)

Comment: @hugodecasta Solved. Deleting my side of the conversation now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated answer, original below:

I've tested this now and think I worked out *why* the below fixes it. Specifically, when the output cell is generated and inserted in the page, it happens in the following order:

1. Page receives data from the server.
2. parses the HTML, including the `<script>` element.
3. *executes* the script, seemingly putting the `element` in its local scope by some means I haven't yet seen. (This is different from how it happens in the nbviewer page, where the output is already rendered, and the script gets it by using something like `var element = $('#ad74eb90-4105-4cc9-83e2-37fb7e953a9f');`, which can be seen in the source.)
4. only then inserts the HTML content in the document.

That means that at the time the script runs, the `element` is inside a detached DOM node. This can also be checked with the following:

`alert(element[0].parentNode.parentNode)` -> `null`

`alert(element[0].parentNode.outerHTML)` ->

```
<div class="output_area">
    <div class="run_this_cell"></div>
    <div class="prompt output_prompt">
        <bdi>Out[28]:</bdi>
    </div>
    <div class="output_subarea output_javascript rendered_html">
        <button id="clearBtn">Clear</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In other words, all manipulation or traversal of the rendered output needs to go through the `element` variable (such as `$("#clearBtn", element)` or `element.find("#clearBtn")` or even `element[0].querySelector("#clearBtn")`). It can't go through `document`, because the element isn't yet part of the document when the script runs.

---

Original answer:

This is just a vague idea: Is it possible the global `document` in this context is not actually the same document as the one `element` is in? There might be some iframe stuff going on in the editor, which might explain why it works after being rendered to a single page by nbviewer but not before. (Elements inside iframes are not part of the parent document, even though the browser's DOM viewer nests them as if they were.)

I would suggest using the `element` you already have to find the button you just inserted in it, instead of trying to find it from the `document`. (I'm not sure what kind of object `element` is, but there should be a way to get at the DOM node it's referencing and then use `.querySelector("#clearBtn")`, right?)

Edit: If the `element.html()` line is jQuery code, then `element` is a jQuery object and `element.find("#clearBtn")[0]` would find the contained button.

(This could also be done with `element[0].querySelector("#clearBtn")`. Note that the return value of `.find()` is itself a jQuery object, and that dereferencing `[0]` on a jQuery object returns the (first) DOM element inside it.)

Comment: This sounds like a really good suggestion. However, the documentation for the `element` object is severely lacking. I can't find hardly anything on it online. I am also very inexperienced with javascript and don't have a clue how to introspect the object and see what it can do. What's worse: today I can't even find the link that I used to learn how to use it in the first place... I think it was on SO but I'm not sure.

Comment: Aha! Found [documentation for `IPython.display.Javascript()`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html?highlight=core%20display#classes). It mentions that jquery is available. Maybe I should be trying to do this using jquery instead of vanilla browser APIs? But I have never learned jquery (sadface). And isn't jquery just syntactic sugar for what I'm trying to do, anyway?

Comment: @RickTeachey if there is jQuery, then it seems likely that `element.html()` is actually jQuery code (it looks like it, but I didn't want to assume). In which case the command you want would likely be `element.find("#clearBtn")`

Comment: YOU ARE A FREAKING GENIUS. I will mark your updated answer correct.

Comment: so - from what little i understand, isn't the jquery code syntactic sugar for the vanilla browser APIs? why would `$("#name").click(doClick)` work but not `document.getElementById("name").addEventListener('click', doClick)`?

Comment: Thanks; I'm glad this solved it! To clarify, yes, `$("#name")` and `document.querySelector("#name")` and `document.getElementById("name")` (should) all do the same thing, except for the first returning a jquery object. The difference here is between `$("#name")` and `element.find("#name")`, because `element` is not necessarily part of the top-level `document`.

Comment: Makes sense. I am now in the process of creating a `JQueryList` sequence/list class using Jupyter's `ipykernel.comm.Comm` system. My idea is to give the object a jquery string and (optionally) some html. When the object is displayed in the notebook, you can select objects in the output cell and the object indexes are available in the sequence instance. Haven't decided what to do prior to display- maybe the object is just dead or something, or maybe it's just empty. Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways of doing it, by returning HTML or Javascript:

```
class C:
    def _repr_javascript_(self):
        alert = "alert('x');"
        return f'''
        element.html(`<button onclick="{alert}" id="clearBtn">Clear</button>`)
        '''
C()
```

or

```
class C:
    def _repr_html_(self):
        return f'''
        <button onclick="x()" id="clearBtn">Clear</button>
       <script>
        {{
        var bt = document.getElementById("clearBtn");
        bt.onclick = function(){{ alert('hi'); }};;
        }}        
        </script>
        '''
C()
```